# Weak chain rule the other way round.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation, weak-derivatives

If
$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is weakly differentiable and
$u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, can we show that for any test function $\varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$, we have
$$-\int_\Omega f(u(x))\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i} dx = \int_\Omega f'(u(x))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\varphi dx$$
where $f'$ is the weak derivative of $f$.

I know that there is a standard result for when $F$ is smooth and has bounded derivative and $v$ is weakly differentiable in $\Omega$, that $F\circ v$ is weakly differentiable, but I am interested in the other way round.

In particular, I am trying to understand Evans and Gariepy page 187.

Comment: What implication are you interested in? What does 'the other way round' mean?

Comment: i think i confused myself. it's okay, i've figured it out.